# Sqlalchemy relationship issue working with datatables

Tags: datatables, sqlalchemy, relationship

I'm currently struggling creating web tables using bootstrap datatables, sqlalchemy and sqlalchemy-datatables.

Sqlalchemy seems generating correct sql query, datatables is populated with correct information.

However when I'm trying to search for record in datatable search field I'm getting an error:

*DataTables warning: table id=main_table - Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with VrfMain.scope has an attribute 'cast'*

I tried to remove any relationships from query, and it works. 
So problem is with relationship somewhere. Can anyone help me please ?

**Here is my sql models:**

```
class VrfMain(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'vrf_main'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    vrf_name = Column(String, unique=True)
    rd = Column(String, unique=True)
    primary_rt = Column(String, unique=True)
    additional_rt = Column(String, unique=True)
    description = Column(String)
    scope_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('subnet_scopes.id'))

    scope = relationship('SubnetScopes')


    def __init__(self, vrf_name, rd, primary_rt, description, scope_id):
        self.vrf_name = vrf_name
        self.rd = rd
        self.primary_rt = primary_rt
        self.description = description
        self.scope_id = scope_id

class SubnetScopes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'subnet_scopes'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    scope_name = Column(String, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, scope_name):
        self.scope_name = scope_name

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.scope_name)
```

**Here is part of flask code:**

```
# defining datatable columns
columns = [
    ColumnDT(VrfMain.id),
    ColumnDT(VrfMain.vrf_name),
    ColumnDT(VrfMain.rd),
    ColumnDT(VrfMain.primary_rt),
    ColumnDT(VrfMain.additional_rt),
    ColumnDT(VrfMain.description),
    ColumnDT(VrfMain.scope)
]

query = VrfMain.query.\
    join(SubnetScopes).\
    filter(VrfMain.scope_id == SubnetScopes.id).\
    with_entities(VrfMain.id, VrfMain.vrf_name, VrfMain.rd, VrfMain.primary_rt, VrfMain.additional_rt, VrfMain.description, SubnetScopes.scope_name)

print(query)
params = request.args.to_dict()
rowTable = DataTables(params, query, columns)
return jsonify(rowTable.output_result())
```

**Here is sql query that is generated**

```
SELECT vrf_main.id AS vrf_main_id, vrf_main.vrf_name AS vrf_main_vrf_name, vrf_main.rd AS vrf_main_rd, vrf_main.primary_rt AS vrf_main_primary_rt, vrf_main.additional_rt AS vrf_main_additional_rt, vrf_main.description AS vrf_main_description, subnet_scopes.scope_name AS subnet_scopes_scope_name
FROM vrf_main INNER JOIN subnet_scopes ON subnet_scopes.id = vrf_main.scope_id
WHERE vrf_main.scope_id = subnet_scopes.id
```

**Here is javascript code:**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#main_table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "{{ url_for('home_blueprint.get_vrf_data') }}"
        },
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
```

Answer (score 0):

I decide not to use sqlalchemy-datatables. instead I'm will use code:

```
all_vrf_data = []
for row in VrfMain.query.all():
    row_proccessed = dict(row.__dict__); row_proccessed.pop('_sa_instance_state', None)
    all_vrf_data.append(row_proccessed)

return_data = {"data": all_vrf_data}
return json.dumps(return_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```